# OpenMP bug with Intel Compiler?

Tags: macos, exception, floating-point, openmp, icc

The following piece code

```
#pragma omp parallel
printf("%f", 1.0f);
```

produces the a "Floating point exception". Has anyone encountered anything like that?

More details:

- No problems when I try to print out strings or integers.
- No problem if OpenMP is not used.
- I am running it on Mac OSX 10.6.8 and the Intel C++ compiler 12.0.4.
- Other than that, OpenMP works fine.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main()
{
#pragma omp parallel
  printf("%d", 1);
printf("\n...\n");
  fflush(stdout);
#pragma omp parallel
  printf("%f", 2.0);
}
```

compiled with:

```
icpc -o test test.cc -fp-trap-all=all -openmp
```

produces:

```
1111
...
Floating point exception
```

Comment: You probably should report it at the support forum for Intel C++ Compiler: http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler/